# Use fiddler to monitor C# requests sent through proxy

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, fiddler, webproxy

Issue:
Consider the following working code.

```
System.Net.WebProxy proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy(proxyServer[i]);
System.Net.HttpWebRequest objRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(https_url);
objRequest.Method = "GET";
objRequest.Proxy = proxy;
```

First, notice that proxyServer is an array so each request may use a different proxy.

If I comment out the last line thereby removing the use of any proxies, I can monitor requests in Fiddler just fine, but once I reinstate the line and start using them, Fiddler stops logging outbound requests from my app.

Question:
Do I need to configure something in Fiddler to see the requests or is there a change in .Net I can make?

Notes:
.Net 4.0
requests are sometimes https, but i don't think this is directly relevant to issue
all requests are outbound (not localhost/127.0.0.1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fiddler is a proxy itself. By assigning a different proxy to your request.. you're essentially taking Fiddler out of the equation.

If you're looking to capture traffic and use your own proxy.. you can't use a proxy (by definition that makes no sense).. you want a network analyzer, such as [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/). This captures the traffic instead of having the traffic routed through it (as a proxy does), allowing you to have it monitor traffic and route your requests through your custom proxy.

Comment: I personally loathe Wireshark's cluster of an interface and having to filter the wazoo out of its requests to hide all the syn/ack/etc white noise, but I understand what you're saying. Just need to find a simpler network analyzer for this purpose. Thank you.

Comment: All you're after is something that can capture HTTP traffic.. without having to be a proxy.

Comment: You can easily have your code send its request to Fiddler, and Fiddler send the request to the upstream proxy of your choice.